# Blender Sculpt Mask bush is not showing the masked area

Tags: sculpting, masking, blend-modes, sculpt

In my Blender sculpt mode the masked area is not showing up (expected it to show up in black). I don't have any modifier at all (screenshot attached). Can anyone suggest me anything please?[image: The picture shows mask applied, in fact it's working as well as when I am using drag brush it's avoiding the masked area. But I need to see which area I have masked.]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the blender.stackexchange! Can you please explain more precisely why it should be marked? I don't see how you tried to mask it. Please share the blend file to have a try myself.

Comment: He's talking about the Mask brush, yes please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 6):

In the top right of the 3D view, there is the Show Overlays button with a down arrow next to it. Click the down arrow and make sure that the mask overlay is turned on. That was the issue I had.

Comment: This was my problem too, thank you for your answer, I could not find any answers on other searches.